# Higher-order helical structure of twisted string

Tags: classical-mechanics, string

Why does twisting a right circular cylindrical, small-radius string around its axis eventually cause it to develop higher-order helical structure? When does the transition to this structure begin and how does it depend on the parameters of the string?